# Is it possible to encrypt the broadcasting packets?

Tags: ns2

I was working in NS-2 research project, in which I want to encrypt the broadcasting packets. Is it possible to  encrypt the broadcasting header packets in AODV protocol in ns2. I was new to NS2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but default NS2 does not have this feature. You have to create you own codes.